# Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module

Tags: angular

I am building an angular 4 application using cli . I have created a shared module and importing that module in my appmodule and moviemodule. I am getting a compile time error Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'SharedModule'

Could somebody tell me what the problem is I double checked the syntax. Am I missing something here

**Error message**

[image]

**shared module**

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule
                    , GridModule ],

  exports:      [ 
                    , CommonModule
                    , FormsModule 
                    , GridModule 
                    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**App module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie/movie.component';
import { MRDBCommonService } from './shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MovieComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NotFoundComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants,
              MRDBCommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Movie module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie.component';
import { SharedModule }    from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
       SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [MovieComponent],
  declarations: [MovieComponent]
})
export class MovieModule { }
```

Comment: Add the FormModule in import in SharedModule and try

Comment: I got this error yesterday. We should report this to the Angular team for improvement as the error is unhelpful and the cause minor, but man did it take me hours to resolve.

Comment: Agree with you on this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove comma front of `CommonModule`

```
exports: [ 
 remove this => , CommonModule 
                , FormsModule 
                , GridModule 
            ]
```

Comment: I really don't understand why we should put the comma before the property, but it works thanks, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try removing the Grid Module from the exports in the SharedModule. The foreach in the error may be coming out of the grid module, i am assuming the grid module is trying to loop through some data.
2. There is an extra comma in the exports section before first module listed